# Android jitpack needs clean build on each release

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I am building a view that has a vertical trail on git hub and added it on `jitpack`, but every time i do a release an download the package using `gradle` I have to do a clean Re-build().

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Is it related to `gitignore`?

Repo: https://github.com/Mohammad-Tabbara/TrailedSheet

Note: i just changed .`gitignore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved it was related to .gitignore used:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore

And everything now is fine.

Would love to know the cause if any body would like to share.

Seams working so far.